# DUDA SOBRE SENTENCIA IF, ELIF

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Estoy recien comenzando y primero que nada agradezco muchisimo a la comunidad por la ayuda.

Estoy creando un programa tipo cliente-servidor con socket en donde el servidor manda ordenes al cliente para que se ejecuten. Mi problema nace en las sentencias, es decir, si el servidor desea terminar la conexion (que escribra "si") y esta procede a terminar la conexion. De modo contrario si no esta seguro de finalizar la conexion (que escriba "no"). Entonces mi problema esta en que mi codigo solo ejecuta la condicion que esta en el IF (en donde te pregunta si estas seguro) y esta al no coincidir deberia pasar al ELIF pero no lo hace. Entonces en pocas palabras da lo mismo si escribo("si" o "no") porque de todas maneras no lee (no pasa al elif) al ELIF. Se queda solamente en el IF.. Espero puedan aclararme que estoy haciendo mal.

Publico codigo.

```
import socket

host = "192.168.0.34"
puerto = 4444
buffer = 30000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((host, puerto))
    sock.listen(5)
    print("\n\n[+]Esperando conexion\n")

    cliente, direccion = sock.accept()
    

    with cliente:
        print("\n[+]Conexion establecida")

        while True:
            comandos = input("\nShell->:")
            if comandos == "salir": 
                seguro = str(input("¿Seguro que deseas terminar la conexion? (si/no)  "))
                if seguro == "no" or "NO": ##SE QUEDA PEGADO EN ESTE IF Y NO PASA AL ELIF EN CASO DE ESCRIBIR "SI"
                        pass     
            
                elif seguro == "si" or "SI":
                     print("Cerrando conexion")
                     cliente.send(comandos.encode('utf-8'))
                     break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Primer punto, `input` devuelve un `string` por lo que no hace falta que hagas `str(input())`, con `input()` bastaría:

```
seguro = input("¿Seguro que deseas terminar la conexion? (si/no)  ")
```

La razón por la que no te funciona es por la manera en que tienes el `if`, para comparar un `string` con muchas opciones se puede hacer con una lista y con `in`, de la siguiente manera

```
if seguro in ["no", "NO"]:
```

Pero una mejor manera sería convirtiendo `seguro` a minúsculas y comparar únicamente con `no`, de la siguiente manera:

```
if seguro.lower() == 'no':
```

De esa forma puedes comparar cualquier combinación de letras que al convertirse a minúsculas sea `no` por ejemplo "NO", "No", "nO" y "no", para no tener que comparar cada combinación.

Para el `elif` donde se compara con `'si'` sería lo mismo:

```
elif seguro.lower() == 'si':
```

Lo que está haciendo tu código en este momento es considerar 2 condiciónes

```
# condición 1 (seguro == "no")
# condición 2 ("NO") y esta siempre será True por lo que entra al if
if seguro == "no" or "NO":
```

Comment: funciona para mi amigo.. Gracias por este gran aporte.